# Spinning drawable ONLY via XML android

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, spinning

I want to implement a splash activity to my app. To do it i have to declare a custom theme for Splash activity on Manifest. I found this guide there: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

So the problem is that i dont know how to implement spinning drawable on this theme (The idea is to place drawable on center and just spin it). But i didn't found any ways to do it: in guides they always use ProgressBar to make it spin.

Is there any way i can do it?